# Javascript, code jumps into the if else statement when it's supposed to be true

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

Okay, now here is the Situation, I'm working on a css3 slide-in and out menu system.

I had to use JavaScript, so I jumped into it. This is how the menu works:
the main page i have a div with lots of child divs (videos) and a sneaky hidden iframe, now when someone visits an other page on my site, the main div go `z:-100` and get `opacity:0` and the Iframe comes forward and sliding down like magic.

BUT I want to go a step further and if he go to an other page, I want the already forward loaded iframe to slide up and down. Now that part does not works. The alerts are there for analytic purposes here is the (probably) problematic part:

```
function betolt(el, frame) {
    var elem = document.getElementById(el);
    var keret = document.getElementById(frame);
    if (elem.style.opacity == 1) {
        elem.style.transition = "zIndex 0.3s linear 0s";
        elem.style.zIndex = "-1000";
        elem.style.transition = "opacity 0.5s ease-out 0s";
        elem.style.opacity = 0;



        keret.style.transition = "opacity 0.4s ease-in 0.2s";

        keret.style.opacity = 1;
        keret.style.transition = "zIndex 0.5s linear 0.4s";

        keret.style.zIndex = "100";
        keret.style.transition = "height 0.4s linear 0.5s";

        keret.style.height = "100%";

        keret.style.width = "100%";
        alert("done with the first part boss");


    } else if (elem.style.opacity == 0) {
        alert("i made it through");
        keret.style.transition = "height 0.5s linear 0s";
        keret.style.height = "0px";

        keret.style.transition = "height 0.5s linear 1s";

        keret.style.height = "100%";

    }

}
```

This code not at this stage doesn't even jump into the first if statement.
It only works if I comment out the else if part and using the if like this:

```
if(elem.style.opacity ="1"){....}
```

but I think this is not right.

Comment: Why not drop in a `console.log(elem.style.opacity)` before the `if` statement to see what the actual value is?

Comment: if(elem.style.opacity ="1"){....}  is always true since you are making an assignment. Is that what your code really says?

Comment: In the second statement you are setting elem.style.opacity equal  to 1.  Looks like you are missing an = sign.

Comment: the second statement is just an example that how i can make it work, the dots resembles the rest of the code.
@pointy  i had no idea abouit that thing exists. gonna try it.

Answer (score 0):

This statement:

```
if(elem.style.opacity ="1"){....}
```

Will always evaluate to true because "1" is falsey, or not zero.  It will assign the value "1" to elem.style.opacity.

```
if(elem.style.opacity=="1"){....}
```

will be true if elem.style.opacity is "1" and it will not change the value of elem.style.opacity.

Comment: it's a misunderstanding sir.  i entered that code to say that the code first part only do work if i declare the if that way as you quoted it. it  the : .... resembles the rest of the code

Comment: Do you have **=** or **==**?  The first is an assignment, the second is a comparison.

Comment: if i use (correctly ) == then it not even enters the  selection.

Answer (score 0):

`style.opacity` holds a `String` data-type, so it makes some sense if it works when you change the test from `== 1` to `== "1"` (I take the `= "1"` as a typo here). It can also hold the two strings "initial" or "inherit" which you might check and if all went wrong if might even be `undefined`.

Albeit it should not make a difference if you use `==`, shouldn't the engine do an automatic casting here? BTW: IE versions 8 and lower do not support `opacity`.

Comment: I tried to handle it as a string so i put it between "   but still does not works.

Answer (score 0):

i found that the `opacity` is little problematic so i went with the `zIndex`
 and it does goes all the way through the `if` still need to do a bit tinkering but i guess i will be able to make it. Thank you people for all the help.